# Rails sign in form don't accept password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've created a sign-in form with email and password authentication. 
When I try to connect with email and password, I get an error "invalid email/password". 
When I try with only the email address, I can connect to the user account.

Here's my sessions_controller.rb :

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
include SessionsHelper 
  def new
    @titre = "Se connecter"
  end

def create
 user = User.find_by_email (params[:session][:email])
 if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
  if user.email_confirmed
    sign_in user
    redirect_back_or user
  else
    flash.now[:error] ='Vous devez activer votre compte avec le mail de     confirmation que nous vous avons envoyé pour pouvoir continuer.'
    render "new"
  end
 else
   flash.now[:error] = 'Combinaison Utilisateur/mot de passe invalide'
   render 'new'
 end
end

def destroy
    @titre = "Deconnexion"
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
 end
end
```

my models/user.rb :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessor :password
before_save { |user| user.email = user.email.downcase }
attr_accessible :name, :email, :login, :password,    :password_confirmation

email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

validates :name, :presence => true,
                 :length   => { :maximum => 50 }

validates :email, :presence => true, 
                  format: { :with => email_regex },
                  :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

validates :login, :presence => true,
                  :length   => { :maximum => 20 }

validates :password, :presence     => true,
                   :confirmation => true,
                   :length       => { :within => 6..40 }

before_save :encrypt_password
before_create :confirmation_token

      # Retour true (vrai) si le mot de passe correspond.
  def has_password?(password_soumis)
    encrypted_password == encrypt(password_soumis)
    # Compare encrypted_password avec la version cryptée de
    # password_soumis.
  end

def authenticate(submitted_password)
    self.has_password?(submitted_password)
end

  def self.authenticate_with_salt(id, cookie_salt)
    user = find_by_id(id)
    (user && user.salt == cookie_salt) ? user : nil
  end

    def email_activate
        self.email_confirmed = true
        self.confirm_token = nil
        save!(:validate => false)
    end

  private

    def confirmation_token
      if self.confirm_token.blank?
          self.confirm_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64.to_s
      end
    end

    def encrypt_password
      self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
      self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
    end

    def encrypt(string)
      secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
    end

    def make_salt
      secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
    end

    def secure_hash(string)
      Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
    end

end
```

any ideas?

Comment: First guess: the user has no password? So encrypting an empty given password will match what is stored in the database? Also: do you want to re-encrypt the password everytime the user is saved? I would assume: only if new record or password-confirmation is present? Also: consider using devise, as this gem has already solved all these problems.

Comment: i'll try to find where is the problem, it worked fine before i add the email confirmation. If i can't find the issue, i will use devise. Thank you for your response nathanvda & QuillyT

Comment: it's ok, just need to change the line : before_save :encrypt_password, to : before_create.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I wanted to just add a comment but I don't have enough reputation so...

My first suggestion is to use [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication because that them does all of this for you and is widely used so it has a lot of community support.

It's a little hard for me to debug this without setting it up so the way that I would debug this is by adding `pry` to the project and sticking a  `binding.pry` before code that is making comparisons.

If you follow through the code step by step this way, are you able to find any discrepancies?

I'm still looking through the code though so maybe I'll have an edit for you in a few.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Thanks Werner. I didn't have enough reputation at the time of writing my suggestion. Just wanted to try to help. I have enough reputation now though so it won't happen again.